# How to display image on codeigniter that is stored in oracle database as BLOB type?

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

I am trying to display an image that is stored in oracle DB as BLOB data-type. this is my MODEL code

```
function viewblobData() {
    $user =  $this->session->userdata('user_logged_in');
    $returnLobValue = '';
    if (!empty($user)) {
        $conn = $this->db->conn_id;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM OP_REG_IMAGE WHERE REG_NO = '$user'";
        $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
        oci_execute($stmt)
                or die("Unable to execute query<br/>");

        while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
            $returnLobValue = $row['PAT_IMAGE']->load();
            header("Content-type: image/jpg");
        }
    }
    return $returnLobValue;
}
```

and this is for display at view

```
<?php echo $this->MY_MODEL->viewblobData(); ?>
```

But its shows "the image `http://localhost/.....` cannot be displayed because it contains errors"

if I remove the line `header("Content-type: image/jpg");` then it shows like below whole page:

```
�M�t9UYG�G��d���~��5 �V�W��jժ�I�P��l6;��Po�ߖ�]��o�_���v��]o7{���Xr?_� ��bp��F3�s>ߙ�K)��f_�w��9����Z#���i�:�V�Y�h�=�����o���{��px=����o��fk���:>����~u�=��w��~9������y�]^����ٹ_���
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: One way - store path in db, and save the images/files in your dir.  Getting the path from db, and putting those path in '<img>' tag can solve the problem.

Comment: Is you are using <img> tag in view ?

Comment: thanks, I know that process but I need to display image from database as there are already stored some images. I didn't used <img> tag.

Comment: I think the header is not set properly, try looking at the browser console, on what header it is giving, another is that maybe the file is corrupt upon insert to the database? another is you `echo` something before or after the image,

Comment: Can you specify how to set header correctly? I checked by changing header content-type but no luck. At the console its shows "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http:// myhost/appointment/user/MM%EF%BF%BD*%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%08%EF%BF%BD%10......."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the image libraries:- e.g

```
    $img = imagecreatefromstring($row['PAT_IMAGE']);

    if ($img !== false) {
        $image_new_name = 'sig_' . time() . '.png';
        $image_path = 'upload/' . $image_new_name;
        $image_name = $ROOT_DIR . '/' . $image_path;
        if (!file_exists($image_name)) {
            imagepng($img, $image_name);
            imagedestroy($img);
        } else {
            $image_new_name = 'new_' . $image_new_name;
            $image_path = 'upload/new_' . $image_new_name;
            $image_name = $ROOT_DIR . '/' . $image_path;
            imagepng($img, $image_name);
            imagedestroy($img);
            }
```

This code will generate image from your data to the provided `dir`. then use that image to display. enjoy. :)

Comment: Sorry, still showing "The image “http:// myhost/appointment/user/........” cannot be displayed because it contains errors."

Comment: please use the 'base64_encode' while saving the image data in db, might data is encrypted. and then decode the data viewing time.